# Generate new columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
Hotel_id    Month_Year      Chef_Id  Chef_is_Masterchef Transition_cnt    Review_Polarity  
2400614     May-2015        2297544     0                      0             0.674450    
2400614     June-2015       2297544     0                      0             0.894450    
2400614     July-2015       2297544     0                      0             0.888300   
2400614     August-2015     2297544     0                      0             0.894250    
2400614     September-2015  2297544     1                      1             0.975200    
2400614     October-2015    2297544     1                      0             0.700719    
2400614     November-2015   2297544     1                      0             0.955500    
2400614     December-2015   2297544     1                      0             0.675200    

3400614     April-2016      3297541     0                      0             0.774450      
3400614     May-2016        3297541     0                      0             0.874450    
3400614     June-2016       3297541     0                      0             0.994450    
3400614     July-2016       3297541     0                      0             0.888300   
3400614     August-2016     3297541     0                      0             0.994250    
3400614     September-2016  3297541     1                      1             0.675200    
3400614     October-2016    3297541     1                      0             0.800719    
3400614     November-2016   3297541     1                      0             0.755500    
3400614     December-2016   3297541     1                      0             0.975200
```

In the `Chef_is_Masterchef` column,

- `0` indicates - `Chef is not MasterChef`
- `1` indicates - `Chef is MasterChef`

When the transition takes place from `0` to `1` in the `Chef_is_Masterchef` column, this transition is indicated in the `Transition_cnt` column as `1`.

So at the point of transition, I have to get the values from the `Review_Polarity` column before and after 3 months and generate new columns using that.

Expected output:

[image: Dataframe]

And also I want another data frame the same as above where I need to get the values from the `Review_Polarity` column before and after 6 months at the point of transition.

Please note I have to do this for each id.

Also if observed, it can be noticed the values in the new columns (PVal_bfr_3mon and PVal_aftr_3mon) are filled based on -3 months and +2 months at the point of transition. The same concept can be assumed for 6 months where we need -6 months and +5 months values at the point of transition.

So please let me know the solution.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried?

Comment: I thought of using a time window that is similar to this concept but didn't find the right method to extract it. Anyways the below answer will fulfill the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but first, we'll list the indexes extracted by the change flags. For that list, I'll get the indexes from three months ago and two months later, and if it's three months later, I'll fix this place. Now that we have a list of conditions to extract, we can extract the original data frame with it.
Next, we create a data frame with the first and last row, grouped by hotel ID and chef ID. The next step is to create a data frame in the first and last row, grouped by the hotel ID and the chef ID, to create a data frame in the first and last row, for the purpose of merging.
Finally, we combine the original data frame with the three month old data frame and the two month old data frame.

```
condition = df[df['Transition_cnt'] == 1].index.to_list()
new_con = []
for i in condition:
    print(i)
    x = i - 3
    y = i + 2
    new_con += [x, y]
update = df[df.index.isin(new_con)]
update.reset_index(inplace=True)
update

index   Hotel_id    Month_Year  Chef_Id Chef_is_Masterchef  Transition_cnt  Review_Polarity
0   1   2400614 June-2015   2297544 0   0   0.89445
1   6   2400614 November-2015   2297544 1   0   0.95550
2   10  3400614 June-2016   3297541 0   0   0.99445
3   15  3400614 November-2016   3297541 1   0   0.75550

up_df = update[['Hotel_id', 'Chef_Id', 'Review_Polarity']]
bfr_3mon = up_df.groupby(['Hotel_id','Chef_Id'])['Review_Polarity'].first().reset_index()
bfr_3mon.columns = ['Hotel_id', 'Chef_Id', 'PVal_bfr_3mon']
aftr_3mon = up_df.groupby(['Hotel_id','Chef_Id'])['Review_Polarity'].last().reset_index()
aftr_3mon.columns = ['Hotel_id', 'Chef_Id', 'PVal_aftr_3mon']
df = df.merge(bfr_3mon, on=['Hotel_id', 'Chef_Id'], how='inner')
df = df.merge(aftr_3mon, on=['Hotel_id', 'Chef_Id'], how='inner')

df
|    |   Hotel_id | Month_Year     |   Chef_Id |   Chef_is_Masterchef |   Transition_cnt |   Review_Polarity |   PVal_bfr_3mon |   PVal_aftr_3mon |
|---:|-----------:|:---------------|----------:|---------------------:|-----------------:|------------------:|----------------:|-----------------:|
|  0 |    2400614 | May-2015       |   2297544 |                    0 |                0 |          0.67445  |         0.89445 |           0.9555 |
|  1 |    2400614 | June-2015      |   2297544 |                    0 |                0 |          0.89445  |         0.89445 |           0.9555 |
|  2 |    2400614 | July-2015      |   2297544 |                    0 |                0 |          0.8883   |         0.89445 |           0.9555 |
|  3 |    2400614 | August-2015    |   2297544 |                    0 |                0 |          0.89425  |         0.89445 |           0.9555 |
|  4 |    2400614 | September-2015 |   2297544 |                    1 |                1 |          0.9752   |         0.89445 |           0.9555 |
|  5 |    2400614 | October-2015   |   2297544 |                    1 |                0 |          0.700719 |         0.89445 |           0.9555 |
|  6 |    2400614 | November-2015  |   2297544 |                    1 |                0 |          0.9555   |         0.89445 |           0.9555 |
|  7 |    2400614 | December-2015  |   2297544 |                    1 |                0 |          0.6752   |         0.89445 |           0.9555 |
|  8 |    3400614 | April-2016     |   3297541 |                    0 |                0 |          0.77445  |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
|  9 |    3400614 | May-2016       |   3297541 |                    0 |                0 |          0.87445  |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
| 10 |    3400614 | June-2016      |   3297541 |                    0 |                0 |          0.99445  |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
| 11 |    3400614 | July-2016      |   3297541 |                    0 |                0 |          0.8883   |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
| 12 |    3400614 | August-2016    |   3297541 |                    0 |                0 |          0.99425  |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
| 13 |    3400614 | September-2016 |   3297541 |                    1 |                1 |          0.6752   |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
| 14 |    3400614 | October-2016   |   3297541 |                    1 |                0 |          0.800719 |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
| 15 |    3400614 | November-2016  |   3297541 |                    1 |                0 |          0.7555   |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
| 16 |    3400614 | December-2016  |   3297541 |                    1 |                0 |          0.9752   |         0.99445 |           0.7555 |
```

Comment: Can you please answer to my recent question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846137/how-to-select-rows-based-on-conditions-for-each-id) which is almost related to this question